# how to emit an array of addresses in a solidity event

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-design, contract-deployment, smart-contract-wallets

Good Morning Everyone, I have created a dAPP that sends ether to multiple addresses at once....but I have one issue, I am trying to create an event where all information about the transactions is stored.. so I am trying to display an array of addresses when the event is logged....is this possible please.

This is the event;
event Transfer(address from, address[] _to, uint etherd, uint256 timestamp);

Then am trying to log the address array in the event log.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but the addresses in the array can't be indexed.

```
contract Tmp {
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address[] _to, uint256 etherd, uint256 timestamp);

    function stuff(address from, address[] memory _to, uint etherd, uint256 timestamp) external payable {
        // ...
        
        emit Transfer(from, _to, etherd, timestamp);
    }
}
```